# convert script to PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I am new to Oracle PL SQL. For the following script, how to make it a procedure? I need to convert the script below to a procedure so that I can call it from an application (SSRS 2005). The application uses Oracle client driver and can't run the script below but can run procedures. So I am thinking to convert the script to a procedure.

If without the Exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('81'); The script can be run by the application no problem. P.S I can run the below script in Toad, no problem.

```
Exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('81');

SELECT 
    ooh.order_number Order_number
    , ool.ordered_item
    ,ooh.ordered_date
FROM     apps.oe_order_headers_all ooh
    , apps.oe_order_lines_all ool
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND ooh.header_id = ool.header_id
    AND ooh.order_number = '27889292'
    --AND ooh.ordered_date BETWEEN  TO_DATE('28-FEB-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  AND  TO_DATE('28-FEB-2013 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-- 1.3
    and ooh.ordered_date >= TO_DATE('28-FEB-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    and ooh.ordered_date < TO_DATE('01-MAR-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: What do you need to do with the result of the query? Spool it, populate a table or whatelse? While movig that code to a stored procedure you'll lose all the implicit job of your SQL client.

Comment: @AlessandroRossi I suppose that it would be a workaround to allow SSRS to query required data properly from Oracle DB. But only OP can proof if it's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without parameters:

```
create or replace function GetOrderInfo return sys_refcursor 
as
  vRet sys_refcursor;
begin

  dbms_application_info.set_client_info('81');

  open vRet for 
    select  
      ooh.order_number Order_number,
      ool.ordered_item,
      ooh.ordered_date
    from 
      apps.oe_order_headers_all ooh,
      apps.oe_order_lines_all   ool
    where
       ooh.header_id = ool.header_id
       AND ooh.order_number = '27889292'
       --AND ooh.ordered_date BETWEEN  
              TO_DATE('28-FEB-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  
              AND  
              TO_DATE('28-FEB-2013 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-- 1.3
       and ooh.ordered_date >= TO_DATE('28-FEB-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       and ooh.ordered_date < TO_DATE('01-MAR-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  ;

  return vRet;

end;
```

With set of parameters:

```
create or replace function GetOrderInfo(
  pClientId    in varchar2,
  pFromDate    in date,
  pToDate      in date, 
  pOrderNumber in varchar2
) return sys_refcursor 
as
  vRet sys_refcursor;
begin

  dbms_application_info.set_client_info(pClientId);

  open vRet for 
    select  
      ooh.order_number Order_number,
      ool.ordered_item,
      ooh.ordered_date
    from 
      apps.oe_order_headers_all ooh,
      apps.oe_order_lines_all   ool
    where
       ooh.header_id = ool.header_id
       and ooh.order_number = pOrderNumber
       --and ooh.ordered_date BETWEEN pFromDate AND pToDate-- 1.3
       and ooh.ordered_date >= pFromDate
       and ooh.ordered_date < pToDate
  ;

  return vRet;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two separate scripts.

**Script 1: define stored procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "PROCEDURE_NAME" (
    p_order_number  in number,
    p_start_date    in varchar2,
    p_end_date      in varchar2,
    p_cursor_out    out types.cursor_type
)
AS

BEGIN
    Exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('81'); 

    open p_cursor_out for
    SELECT 
    ooh.order_number Order_number
     , ool.ordered_item
     ,ooh.ordered_date
      FROM     apps.oe_order_headers_all ooh
       , apps.oe_order_lines_all ool
      WHERE 1 = 1
       AND ooh.header_id = ool.header_id
      AND ooh.order_number = p_order_number
       and ooh.ordered_date >= TO_DATE(p_start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       and ooh.ordered_date < TO_DATE(p_end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
END;
```

**Script 2: define cursor type that will be used by the stored procedure to return values**

```
create or replace
PACKAGE "TYPES" AS
  TYPE cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
END Types;
```

---

*Edit*: as correctly reported in comments **using Oracle 9i or later** `sys_refcursor` can be used instead of defining a custom type, so above script becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "PROCEDURE_NAME" (
    p_order_number  in number,
    p_start_date    in varchar2,
    p_end_date      in varchar2,
    p_cursor_out    out sys_refcursor
)
AS

BEGIN
    dbms_application_info.set_client_info('81'); 

    open p_cursor_out for
    SELECT 
    ooh.order_number Order_number
     , ool.ordered_item
     ,ooh.ordered_date
      FROM     apps.oe_order_headers_all ooh
       , apps.oe_order_lines_all ool
      WHERE 1 = 1
       AND ooh.header_id = ool.header_id
      AND ooh.order_number = p_order_number
       and ooh.ordered_date >= TO_DATE(p_start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       and ooh.ordered_date < TO_DATE(p_end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
END;
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes it will have three parameters for order_number, begin and end date for ordered_date. And I need to return the result set. Can you show whole script? I am not sure about 'create or replace
PACKAGE "TYPES" AS
  TYPE cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
END Types;' Where to put this?

Comment: @thotwielder I edited my answer according to your comment. You'll need to execute both the scripts. Actually you'll have to run Script 2 first: it will create a type that will be used by stored procedure defined in script 1 to return data

Comment: I got this in Toad when running script 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO" to continue.

Comment: @thotwielder Parameters `p_start_date` and `p_end_date` contains date in a string format: '28-FEB-2013 00:00:00' etc. The instructions `TO_DATE(p_start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` and `TO_DATE(p_end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` convert string parameters `p_start_date` and `p_end_date` to `datetime` values

Comment: I understand that. I got a error when running script 1: 'ERROR line 10, col 10, ending_line 10, ending_col 30, Found 'dbms_application_info', Expecting: ;   -or-   :=   -or-   .   -or-   (   -or-   @   -or-   ROW' I am not sure this is related but the version of Oracle is 9i enterprise.

Comment: @thotwielder Remove `exec` from code - it valid only in SQL*Plus scripts. Just leave `dbms_application_info.set_client_info('81');` at that line;

Comment: There are no need to declare `ref cursor` type since Oracle 9i, just use `sys_refcursor`